# What is known about the algebraic completion of a monoid?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

It is the monoid obtained by adjoining all solutions of polynomial equations. I'll demonstrate how to adjoin a single solution to a polynomial equation to a monoid:

Let $W$ be a monoid and let $p(x)=q(x)$ be a polynomial equation in a single unknown, i.e. $p(x) = p_1 x^{e_1} p_2 x^{e_2}\cdots p_n x^{e_n}$ and $q(x) = q_1 x^{f_1} q_2 x^{f_2}\cdots q_k x^{f_k}$, $p_i,q_i\in W$ and $e_i,f_i\geq 0$. The monoid obtained by extending $W$ with a single unknown symbol $x$ is $W[x] \cong W * \langle x\rangle$ where $\langle \ldots \rangle$ is the free monoid with generators $\ldots$ and $*$ is the free product of monoids. Let $\sim$ be the monoid congruence in $W[x]$ generated by $p(x)\sim q(x)$, i.e. the intersection of all monoid congruence relations having $(p(x),q(x))$ as an element. Then in the quotient $W[x]/{\sim}$, the equivalence class $\overline x$ containing $x$ satisfies $p(\overline x)=q(\overline x)$.

Is there such a thing as a construction for monoids equivalent to the algebraic completion of a field? Who was the first to prove that, say, all of the monoid extensions of $W$ generated by a solution to a given polynomial equation are isomorphic? Is there some further condition a monoid must satisfy in order for its algebraic completion to exist?

By the way, I'm not absolutely certain that such a theorem exists, but it seems likely.

Comment: People have done this kind of thing for groups and the situation for monoid is pretty similar. Look at Plotkin's universal algebraic geometry where they look at this kind of thing for universal algebras.  See also Myasnikov, Kharlampovich, Baumslag, etc for algebraic geometry over groups

Comment: Thanks for the references.